# Select multiple com funcionamento dinâmico

Tags: javascript, java, html, html-select

Tenho um select com 4 opções. Essas 4 opções são a quantidade de opções que aparecerá em um select multiplo.

[image: Melhor ver para entender]

O que eu quero é logo que o usuário selecionar a opção de quantidade de palavras mais frequentes, o javascript ja preencha o segundo `select` com o quantidade de palavras selecionado no primeiro `select`.
Para isso, a opção maior que o usuário poderá colocar é 20 e o código por trás (em java) tem uma lista com as 20 palavras mais frequentes. Ou seja, preciso de uma função em javascript que pegue o valor selecionado no primeiro `select` (X) e carregue o segundo `select` com os X primeiros elementos da lista (em java).

Para que ele apareça no `select` o código está assim com o vetor:

```
<select name="vet[]" size="4" multiple><%
   for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ %> <option> <% out.print(documento.vetor[i]); %> </option><%  }  %>
</select> <br>
```

No caso, o for está com tamanho 5 por padrão, mas é esse número que desejo mudar..

Comment: De onde vêm as informações que preencherão o select? Ajax? Fixas no Javascript?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro está em um vetor de tamanho 20 (ordenado).. criei o vetor dentro de um objeto, que usei no java.

Comment: Adicione o vetor à sua pergunta pra ficar mais fácil de visualizar.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro pronto.. olha se ajudou a entender

Comment: Eu faria isso expondo um serviço REST, e.g., `/palavras?limite=5`. Esse serviços retornaria a lista do lado do Java. Do lado do cliente você pode utilizar o evento `onchange` do primeiro `select` para fazer uma requisição AJAX para esse novo serviço passando o novo `limite`. O `callback` da requisição AJAX simplesmente limparia as `options` anteriores e carregaria novas `options` para o segundo `select` conforme as palavras retornadas pelo serviço.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considerando que o `select` `disponiveis` é o mesmo do seu `select` `vet[]`, que vem preenchido pelo java, eu faria desse modo:

```js
var lista = [];

pegaLista();

function pegaLista() {
  var disponiveis = document.getElementById("disponiveis");
  for (i=0; i < disponiveis.options.length; i++) {
    lista.push(disponiveis.options[i].text);
  }
  limpaLista(disponiveis);
}

function muda() {
  var maisAtivas = document.getElementById("maisAtivas");
  var selecionado = maisAtivas.options[maisAtivas.selectedIndex].text;
  
  var disponiveis = document.getElementById("disponiveis");
  limpaLista(disponiveis);
  
  for (var i=0; i < selecionado; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = lista[i];
    disponiveis.add(option);
  }
}

function limpaLista(elemento) {
  while(elemento.options.length > 0) {
    elemento.remove(0);
  }
}
```

```html
Lista das
<select id="maisAtivas" onchange="muda()">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
palavras mais ativas.
<br><br>
<!-- Select semelhante ao seu com name='vet[]' que vem preenchido pelo java -->
<select id="disponiveis" multiple="true">
  <option>de - 5</option>
  <option>voce - 3</option>
  <option>que - 3</option>
  <option>isso - 2</option>
  <option>outra - 2</option>
</select>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9xoxgpsb/1/)

A função `pegaLista()` é executada assim que carregar a página. Ela irá pegar os dados do `select` que já vem preenchido pelo java. Depois de pegar os dados ele limpa o `select` para ficar vazio.

Comment: como posso pegar minha lista do `java` e passa-lá pro `javascript` ?

Comment: Vocês pode fazer como fez quando passou as informações para o `select`. Depois por _javascript_ pega as opções do `select`.

Comment: mas no `select` eu só imprimi na tela. Não sei como pegar essas informações e colocá-las no _javascript_

Comment: @Pacíficão - atualizei a resposta considerando que a lista está no select.